# cannot execute matlab in php

Tags: php, matlab

I have a simple matlab script and I want to run it in php with the following code called matlab_in_php.php.

```
<? php

 $matlab="matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r \"[~,~]=matlab_script(x,y); quit;\"";

 $message=shell_exec($matlab);

 print_r($message);

?>
```

I can execute it in terminal without any error:

```
:~> php matlab_in_php.php
```

however when I test it in the actual environment by calling it in my web browser http://my.ip.address/matlab_in_php.php
I get the following error:

"Error: Activation cannot proceed. You may either: 1. Set an X11 display, and restart the activation process 2. Use the silent activation feature 3. Activate using the license center"

Does this have to do with permission problem or something wrong with matlab license ?

Comment: I don;t know for sure, but if i would have to guess i qould search in the direction of different users. Running from cli probably uses a licensed user, but rinnging from apache doesn't. See if you get the same error when you do something like `sudo -u apache php matlab_in_php.php` (replace apache with the user of your http daemon)

Comment: I used Octave with the same matlab code I had and it works. probably license problem which I don't want to deal with that

Comment: easy fix would be to do a `sudo -u <licencedUser> php matl...` or if you normally run as root(which you shouldn't ;) ) `sudo pap matl...` and set sudoers file to only allow to run that schrip without sudo password.